# Bootstrap confidence intervals of Fleiss' kappa using the irr package

Tags: r

I have estimated Fleiss' kappa for the agreement between multiple raters using the `kappam.fleiss()` function in the `irr` package.

Now, I would like to estimate the agreement and the confidence intervals using bootstraps.

Can anybody provide an example?

### Data

```
R1   R2   R3   R4
1    1    1    1
1    1    0    1
0    0    0    0
2    1    2    2 
n    n    n    n
```

### Code:

```
#load libraries
library("irr")
library("boot")

# estimate fleiss' kappa
kappam.fleiss(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to define a function to extract the statistic of relevance. For `kappam.fleiss` the following code will do the basic non-parametric bootstrapping. I'm using the `diagnoses` from the `irr` package as an example.

```
library("irr")
library("boot")
bt <- boot(diagnoses, function(x, idx) {kappam.fleiss(x[idx,])$value}, R=1000)
```

The function to compute the statistics takes two arguments: the data and the indices of the rows that are part of the bootstrap sample. We then extract the kappa value and to that 1000 times.

The result will give you the following

```
> bt

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = diagnoses, statistic = function(x, idx) {
    kappam.fleiss(x[idx, ])$value
}, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
     original      bias    std. error
t1* 0.4302445 -0.01013167  0.05516197
```

Now you can use some of the functionality from the `boot` package to get improved CIs. The `boot.ci` function computes the confidence interval

```
> boot.ci(bt)
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = bt)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   ( 0.3323,  0.5485 )   ( 0.3396,  0.5463 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 0.3142,  0.5209 )   ( 0.3336,  0.5433 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Some BCa intervals may be unstable
Warning message:
In boot.ci(bt) : bootstrap variances needed for studentized intervals
```

Comment: What does `idx` do? It appears that it is used for selecting specific rows of the data, but what is the content of `idx`?

Comment: `idx` is a vector that contains the indices of the rows that are to be selected. It is passed from `boot` to the user-defined function.